# Hacer una lista de k valores aleatorios en Python sin uso de bucle FOR

Tags: python, python-3.x, bucle-for, random

mi pregunta es si con el módulo random de Python puedo generar una lista de k números aleatorios en un rango determinado **sin el uso del bucle for**.

He estado probando lo siguiente:
Dado un rango [-n,n] debo hacer una lista de k enteros (para posteriormente iterar con ella) sin importar que sean repetidos, para ello:

```
def num_aleatorios(k,n):
  list=[]
  for i in range(k):
  list.append(random.randint(-n,n))

  return list
```

El objetivo es poder realizar esto pero sin el uso de for (de manera que **la carga de trabajo** que introduzca al ordenador sea **más baja** que con el bucle for) ya que posteriormente debo iterar con ella valor a valor.

Agradecería cualquier pista o solución que me puedan dar. Gracias.

Comment: @abulafia pero allí siempre esta usando for, entiendo que no se debería usar.

Comment: @WillyGuevara El no usar for disminuye la carga de trabajo de tu ordenador al realizar operaciones, en este caso no es muy necesario, pero si utilizamos esta lista para posteriores bucles, el tiempo se eleva hasta al cuadrado!

Comment: @Ersanto El tiempo necesario para crear la lista no depende de si la usas para posteriores bucles. Una vez la has creado ya permanece en memoria y procesarla con otros bucles no depende de cómo fue creada. Otra cosa diferente es que llames a esta función que crea la lista _desde dentro de otro bucle_. Entonces sí, el número de operaciones se multiplica, claro está.

Comment: @abulafia Claro, el objetivo de mi lista aleatoria es poder operar con ella TODO dentro de una misma función, es decir, el ejemplo lo he puesto como una función simple, pero mi objetivo es crear la lista aleatoria e iterar sobre ella dentro de una función,

Comment: @Ersanto Entiendo, pero sigue siendo válido lo que he dicho antes. Si la función primero crea la lista y después la procesa mediante otros bucles, lo que tarden esos otros bucles dependerá sólo del tamaño de la lista, y no de cómo se creó en primer lugar. Por tanto los tiempos "crear lista" y "procesar lista" se suman, no se multiplican. Por lo que si el "peso" de esos tiempos está en el procesado, esa es la parte que deberías optimizar, y no la de creación de la lista. En todo caso, la optimización prematura es la raiz de todo mal :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin usar `for` ni otros procesos iterativos como comprensión de listas:

```
import random

def lista_aleatoria(n, k):
    return random.choices(list(range(-n, n+1)), k=10)
```

La función `list(range(-n, n+1))` genera una lista con los valores desde `-n` a `n`, ambos incluidos.

La función `choice` extrae una muestra aleatoria de `k` elementos de la lista proporcionada.

**Demo**

```
print(lista_aleatoria(10, 5))
print(lista_aleatoria(10, 15))
```

produce:

```
[-9, 0, 3, -2, -10, 0, 9, 0, 6, 9]
[0, 3, 5, 9, 10, -9, 8, -10, 8, 7]
```

Comment: +1 Buena respuesta! Si se trataba de un ejercicio en el que se le pedía estrujar la cabeza para dar con una forma de hacerlo sin bucles explícitos, esta respuesta es una solución al problema. No obstante creo que deberías añadir una aclaración diciendo que sigue habiendo bucles implícitos (uno para convertir `range()` en `list` y otro para que `choices()` pueda generar los `k` valores que le pides). De hecho este mecanismo puede ser bastante ineficiente en el uso de memoria si el rango es muy grande pero k muy pequeño. Lo digo porque menciona en la pregunta "reducir la carga de trabajo".

Comment: Respecto a tiempos de ejecución, como comparativa con los otros métodos, el que propones tarda solo 183 µs en generar 1000 valores entre -50 y 50. ¡Impresionante! Mucho mejor que las versiones con `for` o comprensión de listas. Pero algo más lento que con numpy.

Comment: Perfecto! Genial explicado ambos, me habéis resuelto el problema de carga de dos maneras eficientes y diferentes. Muy amables!

Comment: @abulafia. `range` y `choices` son cajas negras: producen un resultado por algún método no especificado. Probablemente usen `for`, pero nada requiere que lo hagan.

Comment: @CandidMoe Ya, quizás en un plano puramente abstracto y funcional, pero al final debe ser implementado en un computador con arquitectura Von Neumann (a menos que estés pensando en computadores cuánticos :-)). Y en un computador así, de ejecución secuencial, no hay forma alguna de generar un rango de números si no es mediante un bucle de algún tipo (for, while, o JMP lo mismo me da, el caso es que en el fondo se está iterando). La diferencia no es tanto si hay iteración o no la hay (pues la hay) sino más bien "quién" está iterando.

Comment: @abulafia. Hay dos enfoques: uno iterativo (uso del `for`) y otro funcional, donde no tienes que contar explícitamente (sólo encadenas una función con otra). Creo que el ejercicio apuntaba a pensar en funcional, que parece ser más rápido en Python.

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar una comprensión de listas:

```
def num_aleatorios(k, n):
   return [ random.randint(-n, n) for _ in range(k) ]
```

Esto es ligeramente más eficiente que el bucle `for` explícito de tu código, pero tiene que iterar de todas formas para crear la lista.

Si te preocupa la eficiencia yo te recomendaría usar `numpy` que tiene operaciones vectoriales que *aparentemente* no usan bucles. Con numpy sería así:

```
import numpy as np

def num_aleatorios(k, n):
  return np.random.randint(-5, 5, size=k)
```

**No obstante** no te engañes. Aunque la línea anterior no parece tener ningún bucle, en realidad hay uno oculto dentro de la función numpy a la que llamas. No hay forma de generar múltiples elementos si no es mediante una iteración. Eso sí, en el caso de numpy el "bucle oculto" que hay allí está implementado en C, en lugar de en Python (aunque es llamado desde pyhon). Esto mejora enormemente la eficiencia del código.

### Comparativa de eficiencia

Si llamamos a la función `num_aleatorios(1000, 50)`  estos son los tiempos que tarda cada una de las implementaciones:

- Tu implementación con bucle: 1.17 ms
- La implementación con comprensión de listas: 1.13ms
- La implementación con numpy: 27.6µs

Fíjate que las unidades de la última son *microsegundos*!

Answer (score 0):

```py
from random import randint 

listado_numeros = [] # crea una lista para almacenar los numero rondón sin repetir.
contador_rondas = 0 # almacena las veces que se agrega un numero a la lista.

numero_random = randint(1,30) # genera un numero rondón de 1 entre 30

# se repite hasta que el tamaño de la lista no llegue a 5 (para el caso que solo quiera 5 numero).
while contador_rondas < 5:
    numero_random = randint(1,30) # genera un numero rondón de 1 entre 30
    if numero_random in listado_numeros: # verifica si el número rondón ya se encuentra en la lista
        pass
    else:
        listado_numeros.append(numero_random) # agrega el número a la lista
        contador_rondas = contador_rondas + 1 # suma a cada vuelta
        
print(listado_numeros)

>>> [25, 21, 30, 15, 27]
```